# DevExpress Winforms: How do I set the correct value in the searchlookupedit box?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

So right now I have a `SearchLookUpEdit` control on my winforms `Form`, and I filled it with my `employeeBO's` (actually an `IdNameBO` with just id and name of employee). When I select a value, it knows the correct value/BO selected (as I can pass data to other methods/views perfectly).

However in the `SearchLookUpEdit` control on my winforms it shows as text `blablabla.Bo.IdNameBO`.

Why does this happen? How can I set the name of the employee selected to show in the SearchLookUpEdit control?

Right now this is all the code I have:

```
IEmployeeService employeeService = _controller.GetContainer().Resolve(typeof(IEmployeeService), "") as IEmployeeService;
_response = new Response<IdNameBO>();
_response = employeeService.GetSL();

searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = _response.Values;
            searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.View.PopulateColumns(searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource);
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.View.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.View.Columns["IsNew"].Visible = false;
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.View.Columns["Display"].Caption = Resources.App.App.RegisterLblContactpersoon;
```

Is it maybe because my data source is filled up with `blablabla.Bo.IdNameBO's`, that's why it shows that value in the `SearchLookUpEdit` control box?

EDIT: here's how it looks: [image]

EDIT2: I've added following code but to no avail:

```
searchLookUpEdit1.EditValue = "test edit value";
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "test value member";
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "test display member";
```

Comment: Did you set the `DataBindings.EditValue` property for this SearchLookupEdit ?

Comment: And the `Properties.DisplayMember`and the `Properties.ValueMember`properties ? Did you set them ?

Comment: I think so, I've edited my question, set those 3 values but doesn't change what I see on my winform unfortunately.

Comment: no you have to set the propery DisplayMember whith the name of the column you want to see on your SearchLookupEdit andn in the propery ValueMember you should set the name of the column that holds the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill in the properties DisplayMember and ValueMember correct.
These properties are used to tell the SearchLookEdit what field from the `Properties.DataSource`to use for displaying and linking.

In your example it will probably need to be something like this

```
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Id";
searchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

These can be better set using the visual designer than in code because you will be able to pick a column from a list, at least if you set the property `Datasource` there also.
And using the designer also set the (DataBindings) property, set the EditValue with the correct columnname

There is a difference in `(DataBindings).EditValue`and `EditValue`
The first is used to tell the control what column to bind to and is usually set using the visual designer, the second can be used to set/read the selected record in code.